# How to create the NAME of the instance dynamically in Python

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

My current system requirement is I have an Master Object for which I have multiple line item, I have structured my data in such a way that I have the Master info in a class object and each line items in different class objects and store them in the datastore.

So to store the Line item data i have to create each object from the class depending upon the number of line items the users have submitted through the form data.

I am trying to create the name of the objects on the fly with the below code

```
(litm+str(i)) = t_det()
```

where t_det() is the class for which i am trying to create the object with name (litm+str(i)) during run time where "litm" is the constant part and str(i) will be the dynamically generated part of name which I  expect like **litm1, litm2, litm3, litm4**

But when I use the above piece of code I am getting the below error and not sure how to get a right piece of Python for my current requirement.

```
(litm+str(i)) = t_det()
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

I am stuck here not sure how to get my right python code for me now, any help plz....

code for class as requested by @Tkingovr

```
t_det(db.Model):              # Tendet Details table   
td_id = db.StringProperty()     # Tender ID, Master table ref
td_ln = db.IntegerProperty()    # Line Number
td_item = db.StringProperty()   # Item
td_itm_qty = db.FloatProperty() # Number Item Quantity  
td_itm_uom = db.StringProperty()# Unit of the Quantity specified
tr_ln_qt_amt= db.FloatProperty()# Line Quote Amount
tr_ln_app = db.StringProperty() # Line Quote Approved
```

Comment: Could you include the code for your t_det() class?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It's an odd request, and I'm sure there is a better way to solve your actual problem.

Comment: @Greg I am just trying out a feature like, we have an Order where the Order will have a Header details and Line items, each order will have multiple lines. so the header details are stored in a different class object and the line items are stored in a different class objects where in the above ex: t_det() class is the line item details class. so i want to dynamically create the instance variable name equal to number of lines in the order, create instance using those name and store the instances in the datastore after storing all the line item details from the html form

Comment: I think a list would work better

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to dynamically set the entity-name, under which the element will be stored in the Datastore?

Its not directly possible with the current API, but ive used the following work-around:

```
classCache = {}
def generateExpandoClass( className ):
    """Creates a new Appengine Expando Class which operates on the collection specified by className.

    @type className: String
    @param className: Name of the collection
    @returns: An Appengine NDB.Expando Class
    """
    global classCache
    if not className in classCache.keys():
            classCache[ className ] = new.classobj( className, ( Expando,), {})
    return( classCache[ className ] )
```

(See https://bitbucket.org/viur/server/src/98de79b91778bb9b16e520acb28e257b21091790/utils.py?at=master for the full code)
This function uses the New-Module ( http://docs.python.org/2/library/new.html ) to create a new ndb.expando class at runtime, which saves its data to the the given entity-class.

**Warning**: This method works fine for ext.db - as everything is done using the class anyway ( class.all(), class.get() ) - so its guaranteed that the current instance knows the class when fetching entities.
In NDB however, get() is performed using the Key-Class. If you do this on a newly created instance, and dont call generateExpandoClass for the class you trying to fetch before, NDB will fail badly.